# Error in TableView when reached to the bottom of the Table

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am recieving this error when i scroll to the bottom of my TableView, I dont think its any error with actually retrieving the pictures from the server.:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (15) beyond bounds (15)'
```

Here is my .m file I cut it to only the actually needed parts of the file:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[self entries] count] + tweets.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0)  {
        NSDictionary *tweet = [tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *created = [tweet objectForKey:@"created_at"];
        NSLog(@"%@", created);
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TweetCell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        NSString *text = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];
        NSString *name = [[tweet objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"name"];



        cell.textLabel.text = text;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"by %@", name];

        return cell;
    }else {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"InstagramCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];



        NSDictionary *entry = [self entries][indexPath.row];
        NSString *imageUrlString = entry[@"images"][@"low_resolution"][@"url"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlString];
        [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url];
        return cell;
    }

}


- (void)fetchTweets {
    self.twitterClient = [[AFOAuth1Client alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/"] key:@"TWEETER_KEY" secret:@"TWEETER_SECRET"];

    [self.twitterClient authorizeUsingOAuthWithRequestTokenPath:@"/oauth/request_token" userAuthorizationPath:@"/oauth/authorize" callbackURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"floadt://success"] accessTokenPath:@"/oauth/access_token" accessMethod:@"POST" scope:nil success:^(AFOAuth1Token *accessToken, id responseObject) {
        [self.twitterClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
        [self.twitterClient getPath:@"statuses/home_timeline.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSArray *responseArray = (NSArray *)responseObject;
            [responseArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                NSLog(@"Success: %@", obj);
                tweets = responseArray;
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            }];
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

}
```

Comment: It's probably either the entry or the tweet objectAtIndex:. You're adding them both together in numberOfRowsInSection: so the indexPath.row in cellForRowAtIndexPath: is greater than the number of objects in one of those arrays.

Comment: Your `tweet` array holds less values then you are using in your tableview, simply you are creating more number of rows in `UITableView` and your array doesn't have that values. kindly review it and check it. - Good Luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There needs to be tight coordination between the return value from `numberOfRowsInSection` and the array access that the code does in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Consider this, your entries array and tweets array each have 4 elements.  So `numberOfRowsInSection` returns 8.  The cellForRowAtIndexPath method gets called to configure row 6.  Your code will do this:  `NSDictionary *tweet = [tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

But wait... that array has only 4 elements, right?  Asking for something at index 6 will generate the crash you see.

It might be simpler to write a methods to interleave the arrays into a single array, then answer the count of the combined array in `numberOfRowsInSection`.  In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, the array elements themselves should be able to tell you what kind of row you have (not the index).  Dereference the combined array and configure the table accordingly.

EDIT - I'll try to make my advice more explicit in code: Let's say, for simplicity, that "entries" and "tweets" are both arrays of NSDictionaries and that your app wants to organize them in the UI entries first, then tweets.

// in interface:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *myModel;
```

// in code:

```
- (NSArray *)myModel {

    if (!_myModel) {
        NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self entries]];
        [array addObjectsFromArray:tweets];
        _myModel = [NSArray arrayWithArray:array];
    }
    return _myModel;
}
```

We call this 'myModel' for a reason.  It's the datasource of the table.  The datasource protocol is asking explicitly about this array (and no other).

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.myModel.count;
}
```

Now cellForRowAtIndexPath is going to ask you to configure that many (myModel count) rows, numbered 0..count-1.  You must dereference the same array -- myModel -- for all datasource methods:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *myModelForThisRow = self.myModel[indexPath.row];
    // get the cell = deque...
    cell.textLabel.text = myModelForThisRow[@"someKey"];
    return cell;
}
```

What if your tweets or entries array changes?  No problem, just rebuild the model like this:

```
- (IBAction)tweetsOrEntriesDidChange:(id)sender {

    self.myModel = nil;          // the "lazy" getter will rebuild it
    [self.tableView reloadData]; // this will call the datasource which will call the lazy getter
}
```

Comment: NSArray *newArray=[firstArray  arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:secondArray]; And then i make the count the value for the                                      numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: I have just done this method and I get a sigbart error pointing to this section of code `NSDictionary *entry = [self entries][indexPath.row];
        NSString *imageUrlString = entry[@"images"][@"low_resolution"][@"url"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlString];
        [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url];
        return cell;` It has the same bounds issue saying 19 is out of 18

Comment: If you answer the size of newArray in numberOfRows, then you must dereference newArray[indexPath.row] when you configure the cell.

Comment: Im sorry i dont understand @danh

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to go read into an array outside of it's bounds.

That array access look very suspicious

```
if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0)  {
    NSDictionary *tweet = [tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

as well as this one

```
NSDictionary *entry = [self entries][indexPath.row];
```

From what I've seen your array `tweets` and `[self entries]` don't contain as many object each as there is row in your table section.

I take my assomption from here :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[self entries] count] + tweets.count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSRangeException` is thrown because you are trying to access an index which is not within the valid range for your array. Try setting an "**Exception breakpoint**" in Xcode to see where it's coming from. Check [here](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions) to know more about Exception breakpoints

This is typically caused by an **[off by one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off_by_one_error)** error.